# Hibernate OneToMany Relation Error

Tags: java, database, hibernate, one-to-many

I'm newbie on Hibernate. I failed when I try to make one to many relationship between two classes.

It gave an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1912)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateDropSchemaScript(Configuration.java:1002)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.business.TestBusiness.main(TestBusiness.java:14)
```

My definitions:

BusinessCard.java

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=BusinessPhone.class, mappedBy="card",
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public List<BusinessPhone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
}
```

BusinessPhone.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="business_id")
public BusinessCard getCard() {
    return card;
}
public void setCard(BusinessCard card) {
    this.card = card;
}
```

Please help me what is the source of error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have two jars in your classpath defining the same OneToMany annotation, but in different versions (one having the `orphanRemoval` attribute and the other one not having it). Fix your classpath.

Comment: This is the jar list I used: derbyclient.jar, hibernate3.jar, antlr-2.7.6.jar, commons-collections-3.1.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar, jta-1.1.jar, cglib-2.2.jar, hibernate-annotations.jar, ejb3-perssistence.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations.jar, log4j.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar, hibernate-jpa--2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar I used the latest version of hibernate and annotations but only changes slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar. Is this can be the source of error?

Comment: Ok, i found ejb3-perssistence.jar is not needed anymore. Thank for helping.